# NHibernate INotifyPropertyChanged Collection

Tags: nhibernate, collections, inotifypropertychanged

What is the best way of getting INotifyPropertyChanged in my NHibernate Domain Objects' Collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find a ready to use library which implements these. THanks go to Happy Nomad(Adrian Alexander).

[Happy Nomad: Collections for WPF and NHibernate](http://happynomad121.blogspot.com/2007/12/collections-for-wpf-and-nhibernate.html)

Comment: I'm glad you found my library useful!  And thanks for the recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/07/nhibernate-amp-inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Ayende is one of the nHibernate contributors

Comment: This is for properties of a domain object, but i need some sort of collection class (like ObservableCOllection<T>) that implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.